# Slopes defined by an inscribed regular polygon

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, euclidean-geometry

Define a regular $n$-gon where $n$ is an even number. Draw a regular $\frac{1}{2}n$-gon inscribed inside of this $n$-gon, and then draw a copy of the original $n$-gon inside this $\frac{1}{2}n$-gon. In this setting we are assuming that both, the original $n$-gon as well as the smaller version of it are both in the same position: placed on one of their edges.

Now, fix a point on the outer $n$-gon, and draw a line from it to each vertex of the inner $n$-gon. Is there a way to determine the values of the slopes created assuming that we are working in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

An example of this sort of an instance would be the following: if we have a regular hexagon, we can draw an equilateral triangle inside of it by placing the vertices of the triangle on every second vertex of the regular hexagon. Then we proceed to draw an inscribed regular hexagon within this given triangle so that the edges of the hexagon are parallel with the ones of the original hexagon.

Comment: If the inner n-gon is incribed in a $\frac{1}{2}$n-gon, which is itelf inscribed in the outer n-gon, then how can the inner and outer n-gon's be "both in the same position: placed on one of their edges"?  What does this mean?  Can you provide a diagram to illustrate the intent of the problem?

Comment: I added a brief description of an example.

Comment: Intuitive response only, rather than rigorous analysis, which is why I am commenting rather than answering.  The **symmetry** of the problem strongly suggests that if the line is passing thru a vertex of the outer n-gon and also passing thru the **corresponding** vertex of the inner n-gon, then this line will pass thru the very center of both of the n-gons (i.e. among other things, you would expect the inner and outer n-gons to share the same center).  This means that you can routine derive the Cartesian coordinates of each of the vertices of the inner n-gon.  ...see next comment

Comment: This means that it is **game over**, since if you choose any other point on or in the outer n-gon, you would presumably know its Cartesian coordinate.  This means that whatever line that you construct, you will know the Cartesian coordinates of both endpoints of the line.

Comment: I am still not clear on the construction. Is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTw1s.png) what you mean? Or should the inner hexagon ($n$-gon) be rotated so that all of its vertices lie on the triangle ($\frac n2$-gon)?

Comment: Yes this construction in the link is exactly what I mean.